# Google Apps Script: How to create an identifier from a tab and replace in another tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

everyone!

I would like to ask for help! I have a question that I think is simple, but as I'm starting now in GAS, I still do not know how to solve it.

I have a spreadsheet, in a tab "refs" I have a column A("location_name") with 235 rows and each row has different name (for example: 'SBM', 'PSA', 'MAU', 'DIA', etc). So, first, I need to create an identifier for each of these "location_name"  and set in a column B with a name like "loc_ID"

After, in another tab "b1", I have a blank column A ("loc_ID") and a column F ("location_name"), and I need to populate the column A, every time one of the "location_name" appears, it will populate with the corresponding identifier.

Here are some example of my spreadsheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v3IWKH7jNLm3m-gvrPqHf7kR-6R_m-7hr8FJAXc5dCU/edit?usp=sharing

If anyone can help, I really appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SQ, can you provide an example of what you mean and have already tried? I'm not completely clear of what should be done by the script and what by hand

Comment: Hey Robin, thank you for taking the question! Here are some example of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v3IWKH7jNLm3m-gvrPqHf7kR-6R_m-7hr8FJAXc5dCU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require Google Apps script.

you can just put in `refs!A2` `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), ROW()-1, ""))` to auto-populate the id.

Then in Sheet `b1` you can put into `A2` `=INDEX(refs!$A$2:$A, MATCH(F2, refs!$B$2:$B, 0))` and drag the formula down.

Comment: Hey Robin, thanks again! :)
But I would like to do it by script because I receive daily some spreadsheets with thousands of lines, and I trying to automatization this process.